Determine the pairs $(x,y)$ of integers satisfying $2x^2-3xy+y+1=0$.
the question
Determine the pairs $(x,y)$ of integers with the propriety that $$2x^2-3xy+y+1=0$$
my idea
I tried writing it as a product of terms but got to nothing useful. Then I applied the quadric formula and got that $x_{1,2}=\frac{3y+-\sqrt{9y^2-8y-8}}{4}$ and $x,y$ must be integers which will make  $\sqrt{9y^2-8y-8}$ be a rational number so $9y^2-8y-8$ is a square number.
I don't know what to do forward! Hope one of you can help me!

Hint: Try to put $9y^2-8y-8$ between two square numbers.

Does it help to note that $y(1-3x)$ must be odd? Thus, $y$ is odd and $x$ is even. Now think mod 8.

$81 y^2 - 72 y - 72 = (9y-4)^2 - 88$

Same method as in here in the dupe, e.g. see my comments here for a very similar problem, viz. $,g=\color{#c00}{3x!-!1}\mid 2x^2!+!1!\iff! g\mid 3^2(2x^2!+!1)=2(\color{#c00}{3x})^2!+!9!\iff! g\mid 2(\color{#c00}1)^2!+!9,,$ by $,\color{#c00}{3x\equiv 1}\pmod{!g}\ \ $

Or, in gcd language (as in linked dupe) $\ g = (g,\color{#0af}{2x^2!+!1}) = (g,\color{#0af}{11})\iff g\mid 11,,$ using, as above, $,\color{darkorange}3^2(\color{#0af}{2x^2!+!1})\equiv \color{#0af}{11}\pmod{!g},,$ and $,1=(g,\color{darkorange}3)=(3x!-!1,3)\ \ $

Duplicate, see above links. Should not have been reopened.

Hint 1:

$$2x^2+1=(3x-1)y\implies 3x-1\mid 2x^2+1$$

Hint 2:

 $$3x-1\mid 3(2x^2+1)-(3x-1)2x = 2x+3$$

Hint 3:

 $$3x-1\mid 3(2x+3)-2(3x-1)= 11$$ So $3x-1\in \{\pm 1,\pm 11\}$ so $x =0$ or $x= 4$...


Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

Please don't make unnecessary edits to questions. This wastes the time of the community reviewing it, and also wastes prime question front page space.

Completing squares we have $$(12x-9y)^2-(9y-4)^2+88=0$$ which yields to $$(A+B)(B-A)=88=2^3\times11$$ where  $A=12x-9y$ and $B=9y-4$
Among the two factors giving the product $88$   we need both even so we discard $8$ with $11$  and $1$ with $88$ so remains the only possibilities
$$A+B=22\\B-A=4 $$ and $$A+B=44\\B-A=2 $$ these systems have the solutions $$(A,B)=(9,13)\text { and }(21,23)$$ which yields the systems
$$\begin{cases}9y-4=13\\12x-9y=9\end{cases}\text { and } \begin{cases}9y-4=23\\12x-9y=21\end{cases}$$ Only the second has integer solution $(4,3)$.
There is just one solution: $\boxed{(x,y)=(4,3)}$

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

Actually this is also wrong. The problem asks for integers, so we also have the nonpositive solution $(0,-1)$.

Since $y+1\equiv0\pmod x$, substituting $y=-1+kx$ in the equation we get $x=\frac{k+3}{3k-2}$. Hence $x=4$ or $x=0$.
